# Constructors are changing values on initialisation?

Tags: c++, opencv, constructor, mat

I'm fairly new to c++. I've come across a strange bug that i've been staring at for hours and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have three constructors for my class, which should do the same thing. However, running a function on them seems to output different format results.

This is my test:

```
void test(){
    float t1[19] = {2,2,2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,1}; 
    vector<float> testVec;
    testVec.insert(testVec.begin(),t1,t1+19);
    Box a(testVec);
    vector<NetworkingUtils::Vec3f> pts = a.getCubePoints();

    float data[16] = {1,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,1};
    Mat test2(4,4,CV_32FC1,&data);
    NetworkingUtils::Vec3f size(2,2,2);
    Box b(test2,size);
    vector<NetworkingUtils::Vec3f> pts2 = b.getCubePoints();

    for (int i =0; i < pts.size(); i ++){
        cout<<"i: " << i <<" Box a:" << pts.at(i) 
            <<"   |  Box b: " << pts2.at(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

And it outputs:

```
i: 0 Box a:-3.22123e+008 5.7856e-039 -3.22123e+008   |  Box b: 4 4 4
i: 1 Box a:-1.07374e+008 6.93378e-038 -1.07374e+008   |  Box b: 4 4 2
i: 2 Box a:-3.22123e+008 1.15704e-038 -1.07374e+008   |  Box b: 4 2 4
i: 3 Box a:-1.07374e+008 -5.77666e-038 1.07374e+008   |  Box b: 4 2 2
i: 4 Box a:-1.07374e+008 1.15686e-038 -1.07374e+008   |  Box b: 2 4 4
i: 5 Box a:1.07374e+008 5.77667e-038 1.07374e+008   |  Box b: 2 4 2
i: 6 Box a:-1.07374e+008 5.77674e-038 1.07374e+008   |  Box b: 2 2 4
i: 7 Box a:1.07374e+008 -1.15703e-038 3.22123e+008   |  Box b: 2 2 2
```

The two constructors being called are:
1.

```
Box(cv::Mat m,NetworkingUtils::Vec3f s):pose(m),boxSize(s){};
```

and
2.

```
Box::Box(const vector<float>& poseAndSize){
    //Assumes poseAnDSize[0,1,2] = Size, [3-19] = mat
    boxSize = NetworkingUtils::Vec3f(poseAndSize.at(0),poseAndSize.at(1),poseAndSize.at(2));
    float mat[16];
    for (int i =0; i < 16;i++){
        mat[i] = poseAndSize.at(i+3);
    }
    pose = cv::Mat(4,4,CV_32FC1,&mat);
}
```

I have no idea on how to start debugging this. Inside the second constructor, mat[16] has exactly the same values as data[16].

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated!!
Thanks!

## EDIT::Fixed!

Aha!
I managed to fix it by moving 'mat[16]' in the 2nd constructor into the header file.

Maybe the Mat constructor uses pass by references rather than value?

i.e.

```
class Box{

public:
    Box();
    Box(cv::Mat m,NetworkingUtils::Vec3f s):pose(m),boxSize(s){};
    Box(const vector<float>& poseAndSize);
    cv::Mat pose;
    NetworkingUtils::Vec3f boxSize;

private :
    float mat[16];
}
```

#### Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I don't suppose there is much chance we can see the `Box` class (likely in its entirety). It doesn't look very overt.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained snippet reproducing the issue. This looks a very complex case.

Comment: I think the problem is here `Mat test2(4,4,CV_32FC1,&data);`. It should be `Mat test2(4,4,CV_32FC1,data);`. Also correct this one `pose = cv::Mat(4,4,CV_32FC1,&mat);`

Comment: @WhozCraig, Box class can be found here:
Box.h [link](http://pastebin.com/W77A9dwc)
Box.cpp [link](http://pastebin.com/LaEjECpD)

@sgar91, changing that seems to recompile, but nothing in the output changes.

I'm thinking it might be an issue with scope now.
For example if I add:
`vector<NetworkingUtils::Vec3f> pts = getCubePoints();`
To the last line of the 2nd constructor, it seems to have the right output there. But not in the scope of the test() function.

Comment: @dran11 both links are broken. I suspect you're right, but without seeing them its hard to say.

Comment: Have tried editing the links to work now.